# Matching pixels on webgl canvas with mesh faces

Tags: three.js, webgl, raycasting

Basically I have a hexagonal mesh, on XY plane, upon which I draw a pseudo-randomly generated landscape.

[image]

Then to decide which face is going to be water and which land, I check for white pixels per face. If white pixels > black pixels, it's land, otherwise water.

The way I do it right now is render the buffer offscreen, and then for each pixel on the canvas, I ray cast to know which face the pixel belongs to, and then sum up all the pixels per face.

Problem is... the canvas is 1000x700 pixels, and it takes AGES to raycast 700,000 pixels.

So the question is... is there any faster/easier way to know which face is located at arbitrary (x,y) pixel on the canvas, without having to raycast the entire mesh to death.

Comment: are you currently using an octree? http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_octree_raycasting

Comment: Nice one, didn't know about that. In my case though, I doubt it'll help, as I only have a single piece of geometry.

Comment: Yep, just ran profiling, seems like with just 1 object it doesn't improve much :(

Comment: well you have to find a way to split it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another solution which performs much faster, 10-15 seconds for 1000x700 viewport, instead of 7+ minutes.

I render to offscreen buffer, then I calculate center of each face in screen coordinates. Then I just run a simple flood fill algorithm, where yellow wireframe pixels are bounds, starting from each face center. That way I account for every pixel in every face.